# Using analog clock in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net

I need to make a analog clock in my windows form menu page in C#.

I have created a user control named "AnalogControl". It uses a timer and here is the code for it:-

```
 public partial class AnalogClock : UserControl
{
    const float PI = 3.141592654F;

    DateTime dateTime;

    float fRadius, fCenterX, fCenterY, fCenterCircleRadius, fHourLength;
    float fMinLength, fSecLength, fHourThickness, fMinThickness, fSecThickness;
    bool bDraw5MinuteTicks = true;
    bool bDraw1MinuteTicks = true;
    float fTicksThickness = 2;

    Color hrColor = Color.Black;
    Color minColor = Color.Black;
    Color secColor = Color.Black;
    Color circleColor = Color.Black;
    Color ticksColor = Color.Black;


    public AnalogClock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AnalogClock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.AnalogClock_Resize(sender, e);
    }




    private void DrawLine(float fThickness, float fLength, Color color, float fRadians,

                          System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(color, fThickness),
            fCenterX - (float)(fLength / 9 * System.Math.Sin(fRadians)),
            fCenterY + (float)(fLength / 9 * System.Math.Cos(fRadians)),
            fCenterX + (float)(fLength * System.Math.Sin(fRadians)),
            fCenterY - (float)(fLength * System.Math.Cos(fRadians)));
    }

    private void DrawPolygon(float fThickness, float fLength, Color color, float fRadians,

                             System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        PointF A = new PointF((float)(fCenterX + fThickness * 2 * System.Math.Sin(fRadians + PI / 2)),
            (float)(fCenterY - fThickness * 2 * System.Math.Cos(fRadians + PI / 2)));
        PointF B = new PointF((float)(fCenterX + fThickness * 2 * System.Math.Sin(fRadians - PI / 2)),
            (float)(fCenterY - fThickness * 2 * System.Math.Cos(fRadians - PI / 2)));
        PointF C = new PointF((float)(fCenterX + fLength * System.Math.Sin(fRadians)),
            (float)(fCenterY - fLength * System.Math.Cos(fRadians)));
        PointF D = new PointF((float)(fCenterX - fThickness * 4 * System.Math.Sin(fRadians)),
            (float)(fCenterY + fThickness * 4 * System.Math.Cos(fRadians)));
        PointF[] points = { A, D, B, C };
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(color), points);
    }

    private void AnalogClock_Paint(object sender,
          System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float fRadHr = (dateTime.Hour % 12 + dateTime.Minute / 60F) * 30 * PI / 180;
        float fRadMin = (dateTime.Minute) * 6 * PI / 180;
        float fRadSec = (dateTime.Second) * 6 * PI / 180;

        DrawPolygon(this.fHourThickness,
              this.fHourLength, hrColor, fRadHr, e);
        DrawPolygon(this.fMinThickness,
              this.fMinLength, minColor, fRadMin, e);
        DrawLine(this.fSecThickness,
              this.fSecLength, secColor, fRadSec, e);


        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            if (this.bDraw5MinuteTicks == true && i % 5 == 0)
            // Draw 5 minute ticks
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(ticksColor, fTicksThickness),
                  fCenterX +
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.50F * System.Math.Sin(i * 6 * PI / 180)),
                  fCenterY -
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.50F * System.Math.Cos(i * 6 * PI / 180)),
                  fCenterX +
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.65F * System.Math.Sin(i * 6 * PI / 180)),
                  fCenterY -
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.65F * System.Math.Cos(i * 6 * PI / 180)));
            }
            else if (this.bDraw1MinuteTicks == true) // draw 1 minute ticks
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(ticksColor, fTicksThickness),
                  fCenterX +
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.50F * System.Math.Sin(i * 6 * PI / 180)),
                  fCenterY -
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.50F * System.Math.Cos(i * 6 * PI / 180)),
                  fCenterX +
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.55F * System.Math.Sin(i * 6 * PI / 180)),
                  fCenterY -
                  (float)(this.fRadius / 1.55F * System.Math.Cos(i * 6 * PI / 180)));
            }
        }

        //draw circle at center
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(circleColor),
                   fCenterX - fCenterCircleRadius / 2,
                   fCenterY - fCenterCircleRadius / 2,
                   fCenterCircleRadius, fCenterCircleRadius);
    }



    private void AnalogClock_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = this.Height;
        this.fRadius = this.Height / 2;
        this.fCenterX = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
        this.fCenterY = this.ClientSize.Height / 2;
        this.fHourLength = (float)this.Height / 3 / 1.85F;
        this.fMinLength = (float)this.Height / 3 / 1.20F;
        this.fSecLength = (float)this.Height / 3 / 1.15F;
        this.fHourThickness = (float)this.Height / 100;
        this.fMinThickness = (float)this.Height / 150;
        this.fSecThickness = (float)this.Height / 200;
        this.fCenterCircleRadius = this.Height / 50;
        timer1.Start();

    }
    public Color HourHandColor
    {
        get { return this.hrColor; }
        set { this.hrColor = value; }
    }

    public Color MinuteHandColor
    {
        get { return this.minColor; }
        set { this.minColor = value; }
    }

    public Color SecondHandColor
    {
        get { return this.secColor; }
        set
        {
            this.secColor = value;
            this.circleColor = value;
        }
    }

    public Color TicksColor
    {
        get { return this.ticksColor; }
        set { this.ticksColor = value; }
    }

    public bool Draw1MinuteTicks
    {
        get { return this.bDraw1MinuteTicks; }
        set { this.bDraw1MinuteTicks = value; }
    }

    public bool Draw5MinuteTicks
    {
        get { return this.bDraw5MinuteTicks; }
        set { this.bDraw5MinuteTicks = value; }
    }



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }


}
```

I am using this control in another form on load event this way:-

```
this.analogClock1.Start();
```

But the problem is that on the page where I am using the "Analog Control",it is just showing up the box but is not showing up the clock and not even the clock is working.

Kindly help me with the code so that I can run an analog clock on my windows form.

Comment: I don't understand the point of drawing 1 and 5 minute ticks in Paint, It will draw again and again. It would have been much better, if only the clock hands are drawn in Paint and not the whole clock. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you provided looks an awful lot like a publicely available sample by [Syed Mehroz Alam](http://www.geocities.com/smehrozalam/). By quickly [inspecting his code](http://range.googlecode.com/svn-history/r109/trunk/AnalogClockControl.cs) it looks like you're not hooking up onto the events for the timer and the form itself.

Adding the following to your **InitializeComponent()** will do the trick:

```cs
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // timer1
    // 
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
    this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
    this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    // 
    // AnalogClock
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.Name = "AnalogClock";
    this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.AnalogClock_Resize);
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.AnalogClock_Load);
    this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.AnalogClock_Paint);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Note, if the code is indeed borrowed from, or inspired by another developer, it is considered good courtesy to make a mention of it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! First of all I would like to admit that I did not mean to show that this code is done by me, obviously I am using the code by @Syed Mehroz Alam but did not knew that exactly, I just searched it when you quoted. Thanks for guiding me his name.

Comment: Again thank you for the successfully running code. Its working fine now. Thanks a lot.!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a windows form item from a thread different to the one that created the form. The `timer1_Tick` is executed in a different thread so you should invoke the UI thread.

Change the timer handler to this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired())
    {
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(this.Timer1_Tick);
        this.Invoke(handler, new object[]{sender, e});
    }
    else
    {
        this.dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I do not have here a tool to check if the code compiles but it should be something like this.

Hope it helps.